# How to change the Login Behavior of Google like we use for Facebook?

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I want to change the login behaviour of Google's login manager to web like this one we use for Facebook in Swift 3, iOS development? How can this be implemented with Google?

```
var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.web
```

Comment: Please provide further information. Do you use Frameworks for this, where do you want to perform the Google Login, what have been your attempts to make this work. How does your current code look like? It indicates you already had a working solution but now want to switch it. Besides: What is the "Web" Property doing? Because The Google Login Library will probably have different enums for a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to implement a Signup with Google functionality in my App. It works but it opens Safari in the background and makes the user log in there. The user gets logged-in in the browser and next time when you tap on the Signup with Google button to register a different user, sometimes it asks to add another account and sometimes it just takes the already logged-in person's credentials and go for server hit. This shouldn't happen. User should be presented with a Sign-in screen, every time the button is pressed. This works well with FB by changing its login behaviour.

Comment: Can you extend your question the way you just described in the comments and give a short outline of all your scenarios you want to consider, which are working currently, and which don't?

Answer (score 3):

Google has removed that particular feature from the Google Sign-In iOS SDK. Read [release notes for v4.0.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release) However, you can use webView Sign-In by downgrading your GoogleSignIn SDK to v3.0.0 (*Any version lower than v4.0.0*).

For that you should edit your Podfile. (*Assuming you used cocoapods*)

`pod 'GoogleSignIn', '3.0.0'`

run `pod update` on your terminal.

Then you can use these properties,

```
allowsSignInWithBrowser = NO
allowsSignInWithWebView = YES
```

**Update for swift 4**

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithBrowser = false
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().allowsSignInWithWebView = true
```

P.S: Since the SFSafariViewController is more secure and a better experience overall. And is default for iOS 9 & above. I recommend you use the embedded Safari View Controller, it's more reviewer-friendly.